# Вывод числа (int) в формате ii. ( Число 1, как 01 и тд )

Tags: c++

Как число ( int num = 1 ) вывести в формате ii ( 1 -> 01, 5 -> 05, 11 -> 11 и т.д. )

Comment: @Flasko

         std::cout.fill('0');
         std::cout.width(2);
         std::cout << 1;

можно через манипуляторы...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout.width(2);
    cout.fill('0');
    cout << 5 << endl;
    cout << 95 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
05
95
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Comment: Благодарю)

Comment: в примере есть одна маленькая хитрость. Если строку

    cout << 5 << endl;

заменить на

    cout << 5 << "/" << 8 << endl;

то вывод будет немного странным - "05/8". (Хотя может это для меня только так странно).

Comment: видимо модификатор сбрасывается после первого вывода